# Is this any plugin QRCode reader/scanner available for ANGULAR 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Is this any plugin for **QRCode reader/scanner** available for **ANGULAR 4 **?

Comment: Aren't NG2/NG4 compatible?

Comment: sorry I edited my question once again

Comment: Anyway, QRCode scanner available for Angular 2 should be perfectly working with Angular 4, as mentionend by Victor.

Comment: yes but can you please tell me the plugin name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually angular 2 components are compatible with angular 4 (and all the other angular versions).

Remember that the versioning of angular is based on [semver](http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2016/10/versioning-and-releasing-angular.html) and that the difference between angular 2 and 4 is not the same thing than the difference between AngularJS 1 and angular 2+.
There is AngularJS and there is Angular, there is no need to specify which version you are talking about in general.

So the answer to your question (with the caveat that I haven't tested) is that angular2-qrscanner is a QRCode reader-scanner for Angular.

Comment: Doesn't semver mean that changes in the major version number are allowed to break anything and everything? Not to detract from your point, but `angular2-qrscanner` could be a package developed for "Angular 2" (at the time "Angular 2" meant "not Angular 1") that was subsequently broken by an API change going from 2 to 3, or 3 to 4.

Comment: Breaking changes or not, if the package was maintained (which I didn't bother to check), it should work with every version of Angular :)